# jQuery + PhoneGap v7.1.1 does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, phonegap

I have been trying for the past few days to get jQuery working in PhoneGap's Hello World template, but no luck. I can't seem to get jQuery to work at all.

In the example below, I added a button to the default Hello World code and I want it to display an alert each time it is clicked. The HTML is:

```
<html>
<head>
  *<!-- different metas and link to css -->*

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript"> app.initialize(); </script>
  <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="app">
    <h1>PhoneGap</h1>
    <div id = "deviceready" class="blink">
        <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
        <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
        <br>
        <button class = "event clkhere"> Click here </button>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And the js/index.js file is:

```
var app = {

initialize: function() {
    this.bindEvents();
},
bindEvents: function() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", this.onDeviceReady,false);         
},
onDeviceReady: function() {
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
},
receivedEvent: function(id)  {
    var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
    var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
    var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

    listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
    receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

    var receivedButton = parentElement.querySelector('.clkhere');
    receivedButton.setAttribute('style', 'background-color: #008CBA;');

    $(".clkhere").click(function() {
            alert("button clicked") ;
    });

    alert("reached this far");

    console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
}
};
```

Above, the difference compared to the default PhoneGap JS is a) My button becomes blue when deviceready, b) The jQuery code, and c) Another alert after the jQuery code to see if it gets triggered. Here, the first alert gets triggered but the button click doesnt work and the second alert doesn't get triggered.

I have tried multiple suggestions about $(document).ready placement, and even tried rearranging the order of the scripts in index.html, but nothing seems to have worked.

Any thoughts would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to add jquery’s $().ready() around your document.addEventListener(“deviceready”), so that your onDeviceReady() will not trigger until **both** jQuery and Cordova have completed loading.

The deviceready event is different than other events, in that if the event is already “done”, setting the listener will fire the callback immediately.  Setting the deviceready event listener inside jQuery’s $().ready() function will ensure that both Cordova and the DOM/jQuery are ready for your code.